# JavaScript Error properties are different in an instance and its prototype - how so?

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype, prototype-chain

I can't make sense of how Error properties are defined. Some are defined on the instance, some are defined on the prototype. Shouldn't it be impossible? I mean, I would expect that a freshly created instance would have exactly the same properties as the prototype. Here's what I mean:

```js
let err = new Error('Test');

Object.getOwnPropertyNames(err);
// Array(4) [ "fileName", "lineNumber", "columnNumber", "message" ]

Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf(err));
// Array(5) [ "toString", "message", "name", "stack", "constructor" ]
```

How is it possible that `fileName`, `lineNumber`, `columnNumber` exist on the instance, but do not exist on the prototype if it the instance just been created and not altered in any way?

Also, the instance does not have `stack` as its own property, is it because it's non-enumerable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How is it possible that fileName, lineNumber, columnNumber exist on the instance, but do not exist on the prototype if it the instance just been created and not altered in any way?

There is nothing magical going on here. `Error` is a constructor function. That function can create any properties on the instance.

Example:

```js
class Error {
  constructor() {
    this.fileName = '<script>';
  }
}

const err = new Error();

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(err));
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf(err)));
```

As you can see, `fileName` is a property that only exists on the instance.

> Shouldn't it be impossible? I mean, I would expect that a freshly created instance would have exactly the same properties as the prototype.

That's not how it's supposed to work. The prototype contains properties that should be *shared* among *all instances*, and the instance contains properties specific to that instance. In the end, a prototype is just an object pointed to by another object (the instance). It is only used when accessing a property on the instance. If that property doesn't exist on the instance, the JS runtime will look it up on the instance's prototype, etc. Nothing more, nothing less.

Maybe you are surprised to see `message` on the instance and the prototype. The `message` property on the prototype is the default error message. It's used if the error instance doesn't have an own message (if you don't pass an argument to the `Error` constructor the error instance does *not* have an own `message` property (see [the spec](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-error-message))).

```js
const err = new Error();
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(err));
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf(err)));
```

> Also, the instance does not have stack as its own property, is it because it's non-enumerable?

No, an "own" property is an "own" property regardless of its enumerability. `stack` is a getter/setter and thus it can operate on the current instance via `this` (or however that functionality is implemented for native functions).

```js
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Error.prototype, 'stack'));
// Object { get: stack(), set: stack(), enumerable: false, configurable: true }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer! Now I get it. It's been a while since I used prototypes and I thought that a constructor function and prototype are the same thing.

Comment: Not the same, but it's certainly all related. The value of the `prototype` property of the constructor function becomes the prototype of the instance. That's  what `new` basically does: Given a constructor function `C`, create a new object with `C.prototype` as its prototype (e.g. `Object.create(C.prototype)`) and then call `C` with `this` set to the new object  and arguments (e.g. `C.apply(newInstance, args)`).